# Newsboat / Newsbeuter is not loading old feeds

Tags: linux, rss-aggregator, newsboat

I use Newsboat for quite some time now and I really leared to like it's plain neatness. However, whenever I add a new feed Newsboat it loads only 10, sometimes 20 (?!) articles that are older then now.

I'm really quite some long time on this, but I can't find the settings (if there exist) how to force to load all (or let's say <1000) articles back in time from the moment of subscription.

Please note:

```
max-items 3000
```

**is** already set ([see documentation](https://newsboat.org/releases/2.21/docs/newsboat.html#max-items)). I want to force newsboat to download more old articles not to keep them longer.

Comment: I know that, on the sites I use, the actual RSS XML file only contains the most recent 10 entries. There's no way for a user to get the older material. There are older articles at my sites, you just don't get them in the RSS feed - you only get the most recent 10. I can configure that number to anything but 10 is default.

Comment: @KGIII: Thank you. I'm not into RSS protocols but are there some wordarounds to this problem? E.g.: other sites that store the links for older articles?

Comment: I can't think of a way and know of no such service that retains the older entries. You might be able to contact the site's admins and ask them to change it, but then it'd take effect for everyone that subscribes to their feeds and they may not want to do that.